# Rails Applying Filters to views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter

What is the best way in rails to create a filter.  So basically I have a html table with rows and columns which lists a lot of information.  Now I want to sort that table by date, by name, ascending, descending, etc...

I do not wish to use javascript to accomplish this, if possible I would rather it used ruby code.  What would be the best way to achieve this?  I do not have to use a table if that is not a good way to go about it.  Also by using code does that means that every time I wish to apply a filter I would have to refresh the page or can it be done without having to refresh the page, can it be instant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is a great railcast about exactly what you're looking for:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax

It shows you both with and without javascript.

If you want to apply a filter without refreshing the page, it means you need to use Javascript.

Comment: I could not be more lost on that page unfortunately.  From what I figured out, that example uses jQuery, and if I disable JavaScript in a browser then jQuery will not work either.  I need to be able to run the filters in a browser that has jQuery disabled.

Comment: Follow his explanations by looking at the video. He shows first how to filter tables without Javascript step by step

Answer (score 11):

Let's say you have a table or a list of persons that you want to filter by name,

1. have a `:name` scope included in your `person.rb` model like this:

   `scope :name, lambda{|name| where('name = ?', name )}`
2. in the `persons_controller.rb` or any other controller on which view you want persons filtered by name, add, `has_scope :name` at the top.
3. on the view pass the `:name` param to fetch filtered results like this:

`<%= link_to 'filtered_name', {controller: 'persons', action: 'index', :name => 'the_name'}  %>`

You can apply filters for ascending and descend order similarly.

Comment: I'v never worked with scope and lambda.  Do you know of any well written beginner guides on how this is done?  I'm very new to ruby and rails.  Your explanation is very good, I just need a bit more in depth explanation how this works.

Comment: more on scopes and filtering http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/search-and-filter-rails-models-without-bloating-your-controller/

Comment: in the view...what is happening at the end on :name => 'the_name'. is :name the actual scope name? or a route?

Comment: @SurgePedroza :name => 'the_name' is a query parameter, The resulting url will be something like this `http://localhost:3000/persons?name=the_name` and this will fetch `person` records with a name of 'the_name'.

Answer (score 6):

You can use Filterrific gem. You can see a live demo here:

http://filterrific.clearcove.ca/

Comment: very nice - was looking for something like this!