# How to implement filters without page reload in a Rails application?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, reactjs, fetch

I’m trying to implement a filter feature in my Rails application and I need recommendation / ideas on how to do it.

I would like to be able to  filter results and display them on the same page (like would do travel websites : skyscanner, liligo, etc). 
When you tick a box on these sites the results are getting updated right away.

This is how the page would look like : Results page

[image: Results page]

My initial idea was to add Eventlisteners to every boxes and use get request to fetch data from my api. Each time a box is ticked it would trigger a request with every parameters that the user selected. And then it would insert the results in the div beside it.
But it feels really messy to do something like that.

What could be a better option ?

I’ve seen that most of these sites uses React to do that. Is it of a great help to handle this kind of feature ?

Comment: this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18080854/rails-applying-filters-to-views) might help you

Comment: Is your question how to approach the js on the front end? Or how to execute the search on the backend? Neither? Both? Something else?

Comment: have you tried to use frameworks or libraries such as AngularJs, Angular.IO, Jquery? .. it is possible to make a solution with them. Because they have functions, to make requests in the background without reloading website.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no 'one proper way' to achieve this in react.** There're many patterns in react but with one common idea - passing props (data, methods) in one direction, from parent to children.

In **the simplest case** you can have a `<Results />` (child component) in `<Filter />` component (parent). Any change in `<Filter />` (checkboxes) can be saved in component state and used for data fetching. Fetched data (saved in state, too) can be passed as prop to children. Simplified `render` function of `<Filter />` component can look like:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div id="page_layout">
      <div id="filters">
        <input onChange={/* event handler */} />
        <input {/* next filter */} />
      </div>
      <Results data={this.state.results} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Using `setState` within event handlers will force rerendering (view update) of both `<Filter />` and `<Results />` components. Local state is used for filtering in almost all react todo example apps - but usually with buttons.

One event handler can be used for all checkboxes, fetching can be [then] 'fired' from `setState` callback. Using redux can be used as common (one source of truth) state for both (or more) parallel components (no parent/child)... you have to learn many react patterns/techniques ... too wide question.

[This tutorial](https://cognitiveclass.ai/blog/react-on-rails-tutorial-integrating-react-and-ruby-on-rails/) can be a good starter but of course there are a few differences. F.e. only one input, value used for fetching directly, without saving in state.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in fact React seems pretty natural to me, since you can use SetState() without reloading the page, as described in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

> setState() enqueues changes to the component state and tells React that this component and its children need to be re-rendered with the updated state. This is the primary method you use to update the user interface in response to event handlers and server responses.

If you go with rails, I recommend you use Jquery, and so take advantage of Ajax and its flexibility,

Answer (score -1):

You can use `javascript along with jquery` as suggested in this [rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax)

or

[Filterrific](https://github.com/jhund/filterrific) gem to for filters.

You can check [livedemo](http://filterrific-demo.herokuapp.com/students) of `Filterrific`.